# How to change the order of child values in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The child values appear in the Realtime Database automatically placed in alphabetical order regardless of how I arrange the values in the swift file.

//Swift File

```
  let order = ["C": C,
               "B": B,
               "A": A]
```

//Realtime Database

```
Firebase
 |_ 
   order
       |_A
       |
       |_B
       |
       |_C
```

How can I rearrange the order?

Comment: Key-value pair is not ordered by nature, consider using array instead.

Answer (score 0):

first you make `struct`

```
struct order {
    let a:String
    let b:String
    let c:String
}
```

after you add value using struct